# Fade in element when div starts

Tags: jquery

I don't exactly know how to name it, I would like to know how could I make function to fadeIn or whatever, when `div` wrapper starts to show. To be more clear I am think about something like that  [link](http://asterialite.towfiqi.com/)

As you can see when you scroll down, the elements are sliding up. 
So I have tried with `offset` of a certain `div` , after one is passed off then function triggers, but its not responsive option, on different resolutions it doesn't trigger on the same time.

If you look the link I provided, whether resolution I have this works the same.

So my questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong with `css` , so it doesn't trigger well with `offset` ?
2. ( I think `scrollTop` and pixels is not good here, because not responsive option for that) there is other/better way to do that than `offset` ?
3. Maybe instead of passing off and element is there a way to trigger function after 'div' starts?

Thanks for help !

Edited: this is simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Cau/)  of how it works. When you are on top of specific div, then it shows. However when you change your resolution, or just minimize browser, the image is already shown while you see the red background

Comment: Have you though about using a library to handle this like stellar etc http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/

Comment: no i havent, prefered self made option xD

Comment: 1. With 'starts', you mean when the div comes into view, right? 2. Could you perhaps show us some code we can work with? A fiddle would be nice as well..

Comment: ye i meant when div comes into view. ok ill eddit post with wat i got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be very easy to do this with jQuery `.animate()` function. You just need to animate `opacity` and `top` properties.

Consider the following CSS:

```
.test {
    background: red;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid darkred;
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <strong>Hello World!</strong>
</div>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$(".test").animate({
    top: 10,
    opacity: 1
}, 1000);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/32L2f/)

Comment: Hey, yea i know how to animate, but my problem is how to trigger it properly, when div comes into view.

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki Use `$(window).scroll(function () { ... })`. http://jsfiddle.net/32L2f/1/

Comment: hm i edited my post, with fiddle how was i doing this. But i guess thats what i needed, if i understand well - it shows when element is in view right? Can it be with less lines , or its optimal :) ?

Comment: @MateuszWinnicki There is always a more efficient way, but I think that the code is ok.